# Django: How to include a view from within a template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to django and I was wondering what is the best/recommend approach to include a view (with certain logic, and its resulting HTML) from within a template.

My concrete example is as follows:
I have a model which is:

```
class City(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)        

class Place(models.Model):    
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.IntegerField()
```

So I need a view to show each city and it's places. Each place should be rendered in a different way depending on its state. Each different way is very different and will probably need quite some bussiness logic.

From my experience with other frameworks I imagined something as follows. From withing the cities template call a view that will render the locations, which will have all the necessary logic and would choose which template to use to render the place:
Example pseudo-code:

cities.html

```
{% for place in places %}    
   {% include_view 'show_place' place %}    
{% endfor %}
```

Where the include_view tag would call a view, which would decide which template to use for the given place:

```
def show_place(request, place):    
    # Here I will probably use more logic to prepare the template.
    template_name = "places/default.html"
    if place.state == 1 :
        template_name = 'places/active.html'
    if place.state == 2 :
        template_name = 'places/started.html'
    if place.state == 3 :
        template_name = 'places/completed.html'
    # etc

    return render(request, template_name, { 'place': place } )
```

**Is this approach possible in django?**

I'v seen the possibility of using an include tag like here: [Include a view in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878689/include-a-view-in-a-template) or
[Template includes and django views/urls. How (do/should) they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130676/template-includes-and-django-views-urls-how-do-should-they-work)

but this forces to register the custom template function with a fixed template:
register.inclusion_tag('results.html')(show_results) #here I would need logic, and make 'results.html' dynamic.

Also I would like to have that show_place as a normal view to be able to access it directly.

I can also do the IFs asking for the state inside the template and use the  {% include %} tag, but that would allow me to have additional bussiness logic that would be in the other approach in the view:

```
{% for place in places %}    
    {% if place.state = 1 %}    
        {% include 'places/active.html' %}    
    {% if ... }    
                {% include ... }    
{% endfor %}
```

What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are going to need to use is a [Django Custom Template Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). You could simply pass a variable to it in your template, then have it decide which view and template to insert in your current template.

An Example:

Your Custom Template Tag (rend_item.py)

```
def return_template(item):
    template = 'null'

    context = {
            #Dictionary of things to pass back

    }
    #if statements that choose what 'template' should be
    if item == 5:
        template = 'item5.html'
    else:
        template = 'default.html'

    #render the template
    return render_to_string(template, context)
```

Template

```
 {# Make sure you load the py file where your template tag is located at the top #}
 {% load rend_item %}

      {% for item in cart %}

         {{ item|return_template }}         

      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.
Do you know if there is a way to have that filter as an actual view? For example if I want to render the resulting HTML as AJAX. Also having DB queries inside a filter does not sound so nice.
I tried but the {% load %} tag looks for tags in the templatetags folder, so can't do the register in the views.py file.

Thanks again!

Comment: django doesn't provide for "views within templates".  The custom tag is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 6):

Even though the question was asked **quite** a while back, I was searching for the same kinda feature.

I believe I found the answer to the initial question and the follow up question to JcKelly's post -> 'filter as an actual view' (in which I assume filter means render).

I found this snippet (of a *custom templatetag*, see post JcKelley for info on custom templatetag) on the web:

```
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1568/
```

It was outdated for me. Thus I followed it's approach and came up with:

**Your TemplateTag.py file**

```
from django.template import Library, Node, Variable, TemplateSyntaxError
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse, resolve, NoReverseMatch
register = Library()


class ViewNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, url_or_view, args, kwargs):
        self.url_or_view = url_or_view
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def render(self, context):
        if 'request' not in context:
            raise TemplateSyntaxError("No request has been made.")

        url_or_view = Variable(self.url_or_view).resolve(context)
        try:
            view, args, kwargs = resolve(reverse(url_or_view))
        except NoReverseMatch:
            view, args, kwargs = resolve(url_or_view)

        try:
            if callable(view):
                self.args += args
                self.kwargs.update(**kwargs)
                return (view(context['request'], *self.args, **self.kwargs)
                        .rendered_content)
            raise "%r is not callable" % view
        except:
            if settings.DEBUG:
                raise
        return None


@register.tag(name='view')
def do_view(parser, token):
    args, kwargs, tokens = [], {}, token.split_contents()
    if len(tokens) < 2:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(
            f"{token.contents.split()[0]} tag requires one or more arguments")

    for t in tokens[2:]:
        kw = t.find("=")
        args.append(t) if kw == -1 else kwargs.update({str(t[:kw]): t[kw+1:]})
    return ViewNode(tokens[1], args, kwargs)
```

**Your Template-file.html**
-> example of usage

Using a view's path name, 
(*see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns for info on path names*):

```
     {% view "mymodule:inner" %}
     {% view "mymodule:inner" "value" %}
     {% view "mymodule:inner" keyword="value" %}
     {% view "mymodule:inner" arg_expr %}
     {% view "mymodule:inner" keyword=arg_expr %}
```

Using a URL (or something that evaluates to a URL):

```
     {% view "/inner" %}
     {% view url_expr %}
```

Hope it may help someone!

Comment: thanks - this was just what I needed. Don't know why but I couldn't get my class based views that took parameters to resolve. Passing the resolved url to view worked though:
                                    {% url "app:update_thing" pk=object.id as this_url %}
                                    {% view this_url %}

Comment: This does not work in Django (5, 0, 2, 'final', 0)
The issue is around 
```return (view(context['request'], *self.args, **self.kwargs)
                        .rendered_content)```
I believe it is wanting a string returned. I tried render() and render_as_string() in my view to no avail.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue as Corey above, and was able to get things to render as expected by integrating `TemplateResponse` into the `get` method of the view:

```template_response = TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, content)
        return template_response.render()```